# foreach com erro

Tags: php, foreach

Galeta alguém pode me dar um help aqui, fiz esse trem pra pegar os dias de semana, até tudo bem, mais o **foreach($periodo as $item)** não lista o último dia, alguém pode me dizer oque estou fazendo de errado!

```
$ini        = new DateTime('2019-02-01');
$fim        = new DateTime('2019-02-28');

$periodo    = new DatePeriod($ini, new DateInterval('P1D'), $fim);

foreach($periodo as $item){

if(substr($item->format("D"), 0, 1) != 'S'){

    echo  $item->format('d/m/Y') . " - " . $item->format("N") . " - " . $item->format("D") . "<br>";

    if($item->format("N") == 5){
        echo "<br><br>";
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para colocar a última data na lista é necessário adicionar um dia à sua data fim, com o método `modify()`

```
$ini = new DateTime('2019-02-01');
$fim = new DateTime('2019-02-28');
$fim->modify('+1 day');
```

Comment: Perfeito, valeu mesmo, gradecido

Comment: Olá @MarcosC.Anzolin. Se a resposta lhe foi útil e está correta, marque-a como tal! [Porque é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)